# Is checking for cin.eof() really necessary?

Tags: c++

I have written a simple program that reads character input from the keyboard within a For loop. My professor has taken away 10 points for not checking the input using cin.eof. I don't understand why this is necessary? Presumably any non-integer character should be acceptable. The prof specifically said not to check for integers.

I ran the program using Visual Studio 10, and entered CTRL-Z as input. The program quit anyway even though I did not specifically code for the EOF condition. Can someone explain why? And is the professor correct insisting to check for cin.eof or is this antiquated style?

Here is an example code snippet:

```
cout << "Enter a list of 10 words" << endl;

for (i= 0;i< MAX; i++) { 
    getline(cin, input);
    Word word(input);
    noun_array[nElements]= word;
}
```

Comment: why didn't you ask at Stack Overflow? http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/129632/165773

Comment: @gnat: Because this one might actually fit here? It's a question on style, not an implementation, which doesn't really fit either, but it feels like a better fit here than there.

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/a/1284294/136208

Answer (score 8):

> I ran the program using Visual Studio 10, and entered CTRL-Z as input.
>   The program quit anyway even though I did not specifically code for
>   the EOF condition. Can someone explain why?

The program doesn't quit.

The end-of-file character (<kbd>CTRL</kbd>-<kbd>Z</kbd> on the keyboard) sets the internal state flag of `std::cin` to `eofbit`, which must be cleared with [basic_ios::clear()](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_ios/clear) before following calls to `getline` will work properly.

The loop is executed `MAX` times but `getline` won't append characters to `input`.

I'm not sure this is what you want. If it works, it's probably a matter of luck.

How to check? `eof()` has some downsides:

> Both eof() and feof() check the state of an input stream to see if an
>   end-of-file condition has occurred. Such  a condition can only occur
>   following an attempted read operation. If you call either function
>   without previously performing a read, your code is wrong! Never loop
>   on an eof function.

<sup>(From [All about EOF](http://latedev.wordpress.com/2012/12/04/all-about-eof/))</sup>

The EOF state may not get set until after a read is attempted past the end of file. That is, reading the last byte from a file might not set the EOF state.

Moreover

```
if (!std::cin.eof())
```

will test for end-of-file, not for errors.

You should prefer:

```
if (getline(std::cin, input))
{
  // ...
}
```

See also [C++ FAQ Section 15.5](http://www.parashift.com/c++-faq-lite/istream-and-eof.html) and [How to determine whether it is EOF when using getline() in c++?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1264052/3235496)

**EDIT**

It should be something like:

```
std::cout << "Enter a list of 10 words" << std::endl;

for (unsigned i(0); i < MAX && std::getline(std::cin, input); ++i)
{
  // ...
  // Word word(input);
  // noun_array[nElements] = word;
  // ...
}
```

This way the program performs its processing only with a valid input.

Comment: I still don't understand. A while loop will never complete unless the user enters CTRL-Z, in other words, to make the while condition return FALSE. I want to stop reading input when MAX is reached, but the user will not enter the EOF character. So this test still seems pointless to me.

Comment: `while`, `for`, `if` there are many ways to perform the task. The important thing is that all input should be checked and validated. I've edited the answer. Hope it helps.

Comment: ⁺¹, though a little correction: EOF is `Ctrl+d`. The `Ctrl+z` suspends the app. It might look as if the app did quit, but it didn't.

Comment: @Hi-Angel That is true for Unix systems. In Windows (/MS-DOS) a line consisting of a single `Ctrl Z` is, by convention, an End Of File marker (e.g. https://stackoverflow.com/a/1782134/3235496, https://stackoverflow.com/q/11378899/3235496). Anyhow a clarification was needed in this regard.